# Authorize.net Accept Hosted Redirect Methods webhook response have responseCode 0

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-webhooks

We are using Accept Hosted Redirect Methods for our payment.

Some transaction's webhook callback have `responseCode 0`.
But these transactions are listed as approved in ANET account.
In our webhook code , we are processing only the responses with `responseCode 1`.
But when we take the transaction details using the ANET PHP SDK(Method `GetTransactionDetails` ) , it returns response code as `1`.

Can any one help us to identify why the `responseCode` parameter have value `0`.

Response received via hook callback

```json
{
    "notificationId": "************",
    "eventType": "net.authorize.payment.authcapture.created",
    "eventDate": "2021-04-14T21:52:39.1188391Z",
    "webhookId": "********************",
    "payload": {
        "responseCode": 0,
        "authAmount": 115.00,
        "merchantReferenceId": "******************",
        "invoiceNumber": "**********",
        "entityName": "transaction",
        "id": "************"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the day "2021-04-14T21:52:39.1188391Z" there is some update happens from the ANET Side. As per the feedback from the ANET Support team they are worked on the WEBHOOK section exactly on the same day

Comment: Yes, that was the issue.We have confirmed that with the ANET Support Team.